# Chrome console returns array instead of its value, why is that?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-console

```
var meals = {
  breakfast: "oatmeal",
  lunch: "turkey sandwich",
  dinner: "steak and potatoes"
};
```

=> undefined

```
Object.assign({}, meals, {breakfast: ['oatmeal', 'banana']})
```

=> {breakfast: Array(2), lunch: "turkey sandwich", dinner: "steak and potatoes"}

Why is chrome console displaying `Array(2)` instead of displaying the actual value of the array which is `['oatmeal', 'banana']`.

Comment: If you click on it, it should expand and show you the actual contents of that array.

Answer (score 1):

The value that chrome logs to the console is an array itself. You can check it by expanding it. It is just displayed as `array(2)` for brevity. You can always expand it to get it to display the full contents of objects and therefore the full array `breakfast` as well.

The nested values are just compacted while showing it for properly displaying objects and giving you a proper view of the nesting that goes on in the object.

Check below, the value returned by `Object.assign(...)` is just as expected. The same can be verified by expanding the object logged by chrome console.

```js
var meals = {
  breakfast: "oatmeal",
  lunch: "turkey sandwich",
  dinner: "steak and potatoes"
};

console.log(Object.assign({}, meals, {breakfast: ['oatmeal', 'banana']}))
```